# State updates are unclear and not rendering my catalog of products based on menu selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm updating two states where `setProductsShow` depends on `setSelectedCategories`.  `setSelectedCategories` is updated first then `setProductsShow` is updated to render products.

There are plenty of solutions on React state updates and I've read other answers on the matter but I'm confused on the order of which the states update for my specific case.

#### products

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Potato",
    "category": "food"
  },
  {
    "name": "iPhone",
    "category": "tech"
  }
]
```

#### menuItems

```json
[
  {
    "name": "tech",
    "menuSelect": false
  },
  {
    "name": "food",
    "menuSelect": false
  }
]
```

```js
  const [productsShow, setProductsShow] = useState(products)
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState(menuItems)  // Default all items selected

  // Event is triggered by a change in menu selection; code not shown 
  function handleChangeMenu(event) {
    let { name, checked } = event.target

    // Update categories based on menu selection
    setSelectedCategories(category => (
      category.map(item => item.name == name ? {
        ...item,
        menuSelect: checked
      } : item)
    ))

    // If category is selected, then push onto an array
    let flatSelected = []

    setSelectedCategories(c => {
      flatSelected = c.map(selected => {
        if (selected.menuSelect) {
          flatSelected.push(selected.name)
        }
      })
      return c  // Return the state since we're only reading 
    })
    console.log("FLATSELECTED")
    console.log(flatSelected)

    // Render products which are marked as TRUE in array of menu items "flatSelected[]"
    setProductsShow(() => {
      console.log("INSIDE SETPRODUCTSSHOW")
      console.log(products.filter(product => flatSelected.includes(product.category)))

      console.log("FLATSELECTED")
      console.log(flatSelected)
      products.filter(product => flatSelected.includes(product.category))
    })
  }
```

The outcome I get is `console.log(products.filter(product => flatSelected.includes(product.category)))` prints out an empty array.

Comment: I don't think the syntax of your code snippet is valid: `setProductsShow` at the bottom is an arrow function without curly brackets that has multiple statements in it. Editing it would be helpful for those looking at the question!

Comment: Much appreciated @JKillian, I've made the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting state and try to access the state before the component has been rerenderd. The second time you call setSelectedCategories categories hasn't had time to get updated.

Set state at the end of the function and it should work:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const products = [
  {
    name: "Potato",
    category: "food",
  },
  {
    name: "iPhone",
    category: "tech",
  },
];

const menuItems = [
  {
    name: "tech",
    menuSelect: false,
  },
  {
    name: "food",
    menuSelect: false,
  },
];

function App() {
  const [productsShow, setProductsShow] = useState(products);
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState(menuItems);

  function handleChangeMenu(event) {
    //mock the event
    let { name, checked } = { name: "tech", checked: true };

    //updating catagory
    const newSelectedCategories = menuItems.map((category) =>
      category.name === name ? { ...category, menuSelect: checked } : category
    );

    //updating products
    const newProductsShow = products.filter((product) =>
      newSelectedCategories.some(
        ({ name, menuSelect }) => name === product.category && menuSelect
      )
    );

    // Update state based on menu selection
    setSelectedCategories(newSelectedCategories);
    setProductsShow(newProductsShow);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleChangeMenu}> Toogle tech </button>
      {productsShow.map((product) => (
        <div> {product.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you!  It works!  I see now it's best to deal with variables then update the states last.